# accessing accossiated array values not working as expected

Tags: php

I have this function which returns a array object

```
static public function GetFeaturedArticle($db) {

    try {

        $statement = $db->prepare("SELECT a.*, u.username FROM articles a LEFT JOIN users u ON a.user_id = u.id WHERE a.featured = TRUE LIMIT 1");
        $statement->execute();      

        while ($record = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            // i have to process some data here and i want to return 
            // associative array back
            $obj = new self($db);
            $obj->processInput($record);
            $obj->processPhotoField();

        }

    } catch (PDOException $ex) {
        if (HOST_TYPE ==="dev") {
            echo "<pre>"; print_r($ex); echo "</pre>";
        }
        throw ($ex);
    }
    // the return type i'm not sure of
    return get_object_vars($obj);       
}
```

and Im trying to access my properties like this

```
<?php echo $this->featured_article->data["id"]; ?>
```

but i get a fatal error:
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\winepress\www\templates\home.tpl.php on line 27

and this is my var dump

```
array (size=8)
  'db' => 
    object(PDO)[1]
  'id' => int 2
  'data' => 
    array (size=11)
      'id' => int 2
      'category_id' => int 1
      'user_id' => int 6
      'username' => string 'kirk' (length=4)
      'title' => string 'In ultricies, tortor in placerat dignissim, sapien leo feugiat augue' (length=68)
      'description' => string 'In suscipit orci ac turpis ultricies tincidunt. Quisque volutpat turpis ut leo interdum sodales. Sed fermentum magna consequat ante ultrices, a egestas est posuere. Phasellus varius massa in est sollicitudin laoreet' (length=215)
      'content' => string '<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In suscipit orci ac turpis ultricies tincidunt. Quisque volutpat turpis ut leo interdum sodales. Sed fermentum magna consequat ante ultrices, a egestas est posuere. Phasellus varius massa in est sollicitudin laoreet. Maecenas sit amet consequat orci. Aliquam pharetra ante sit amet urna volutpat feugiat. Praesent sed sapien in est pellentesque mollis. Proin nisl felis, imperdiet quis nunc at, bibendum sagittis elit. Vestibulum in arcu quis est phare'... (length=3214)
      'created_date' => string '2014-07-10 14:05:55' (length=19)
      'featured' => int 1
      'enable_comments' => int 0
      'photo' => 
        object(Image)[6]
          public 'verbose_debug' => boolean false
          public 'error' => string '' (length=0)
          public 'errno' => int 0
          public 'filename' => string 'images/articles/pic_2.jpg' (length=25)
          public 'mimetype' => string 'image/jpeg' (length=10)
          public 'width' => int 484
          public 'height' => int 266
          public 'htmlDimensions' => string 'width="484" height="266"' (length=24)
          public 'getimagesize_data' => 
            array (size=7)
              ...
          public 'getimagesize_info' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'files_superglobal_entry' => null
          public 'thumbnailJpegQuality' => int 85
  'allowedFields' => 
    array (size=11)
      0 => string 'id' (length=2)
      1 => string 'category_id' (length=11)
      2 => string 'user_id' (length=7)
      3 => string 'username' (length=8)
      4 => string 'title' (length=5)
      5 => string 'description' (length=11)
      6 => string 'content' (length=7)
      7 => string 'created_date' (length=12)
      8 => string 'featured' (length=8)
      9 => string 'enable_comments' (length=15)
      10 => string 'photo' (length=5)
  'validation' => 
    array (size=4)
      'title' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string 'Validation::checkRequired' (length=25)
          1 => string 'Validation::checkName' (length=21)
      'description' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'Validation::checkRequired' (length=25)
      'content' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'Validation::checkRequired' (length=25)
      'photo' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'ArticleModel::checkPhotoIsImageObject' (length=37)
  'input' => 
    array (size=11)
      'id' => int 2
      'category_id' => int 1
      'user_id' => int 6
      'photo' => string 'pic_2.jpg' (length=9)
      'title' => string 'In ultricies, tortor in placerat dignissim, sapien leo feugiat augue' (length=68)
      'description' => string 'In suscipit orci ac turpis ultricies tincidunt. Quisque volutpat turpis ut leo interdum sodales. Sed fermentum magna consequat ante ultrices, a egestas est posuere. Phasellus varius massa in est sollicitudin laoreet' (length=215)
      'content' => string '<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In suscipit orci ac turpis ultricies tincidunt. Quisque volutpat turpis ut leo interdum sodales. Sed fermentum magna consequat ante ultrices, a egestas est posuere. Phasellus varius massa in est sollicitudin laoreet. Maecenas sit amet consequat orci. Aliquam pharetra ante sit amet urna volutpat feugiat. Praesent sed sapien in est pellentesque mollis. Proin nisl felis, imperdiet quis nunc at, bibendum sagittis elit. Vestibulum in arcu quis est phare'... (length=3214)
      'created_date' => string '2014-07-10 14:05:55' (length=19)
      'featured' => int 1
      'enable_comments' => int 0
      'username' => string 'kirk' (length=4)
  'debugOutput' => null
  'errors' => 
    array (size=11)
      'id' => string '' (length=0)
      'category_id' => string '' (length=0)
      'user_id' => string '' (length=0)
      'username' => string '' (length=0)
      'title' => string '' (length=0)
      'description' => string '' (length=0)
      'content' => string '' (length=0)
      'created_date' => string '' (length=0)
      'featured' => string '' (length=0)
      'enable_comments' => string '' (length=0)
      'photo' => string '' (length=0)
```

how do i accesss my data properties and echo out my data like this

```
<?php echo $this->featured_article->data["id"]; ?>
```

Comment: check with : `<?php echo $this->featured_article["data"]["id"]; ?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to access a class property with

```
featured_article->data
```

But according to your `var_dump` output you have an array.

So you have to access it with

```
featured_article['data']
```

So your line should be

```
<?php echo $this->featured_article['data']['id']; ?>
```

Comment: thanks for you're help that partly worked but now Im having problems accessing the photo data I need to echo out ["photo"]fieldname;

Comment: Well this is an `Image`  object. As long as you don't have a magic `__toString()` method defined for a class you can't echo it out and get a meaningful result.